# Sorting Core Data fetch results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

My NSManagedObject has a property NSDate with format: `2012-03-27 14:43:22 +0000`. I want to sort my results by date, so I do:
`NSSortDescriptor *sort= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];`

And I separate into sections using sectionNameKeyPath:
`NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"createDate" cacheName:nil];`

However, I want to sort by days, not by exact date. Currently, if I have two createDates of the same day but seconds apart, they are sorted into separate sections. I want to sort all objects with the same day into the same section. How would I do this?

Comment: found a similar question here:
[Sort NSDate without respect to the time of day - just the date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651733/sort-nsdate-without-respect-to-the-time-of-day-just-the-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two posts that I came across the other day that discuss non-standard sections. It will give you a few cool directions and ideas:

[Using custom sections with NSFetchedResultsController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384345/using-custom-sections-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller)
[Group by weekdays with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260014/group-by-weekdays-with-core-data)

Answer (score 1):

Just a rough thought. You can store the date with string "2012-03-27", I think you can sort them by days.

Comment: If you are not sure of an answer post it as a comment please. Otherwise people will down vote your answers.